# Element shaking between statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you scroll down slowly near the blue box (at this moment second statement going to be execute, I mean `else` statement) There is a glitch and shaking on the green box, why this happening?

```js
var target = $('.product-info-main').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var footer = $('.page-footer').offset().top;
  var element = $('.box-tocart').offset().top;
  
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  if ((scrollTop >= target) && (scrollTop + windowHeight <= footer)) {
    $('.box-tocart').addClass('tobefix');
    //console.log('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.box-tocart').removeClass('tobefix');
    //console.log('not fixed');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 0;
}

#nothing {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.product-info-main {
  height: 1000px;
}

.box-tocart {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-tocart.tobefix {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nothing"></div>
<div class="product-info-main">
  
</div>

<div class="box-tocart"></div>
<div class="page-footer"></div>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: when you add the `fixed` property to the green box it removes it from the page flow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values - doing so likely changes the value of the footer's offset top and so it causes the flickering while its in the ambiguous area before its all the way in.

Comment: So is there any solution to avoid this? @lemieuxster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this issue you position:sticky fixed positioned elements will have this issue.

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
>   value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
>   containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to
>   value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
>   scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting
>   the opposite edge of its containing block.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```js
var target = $('.product-info-main').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var footer = $('.page-footer').offset().top;
  var element = $('.box-tocart').offset().top;
  
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  if ((scrollTop >= target) && (scrollTop + windowHeight <= footer)) {
    $('.box-tocart').addClass('tobefix');
    //console.log('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.box-tocart').removeClass('tobefix');
    //console.log('not fixed');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 0;
}

#nothing {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.product-info-main {
  height: 1000px;
}

.box-tocart {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-tocart.tobefix {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nothing"></div>
<div class="product-info-main">
  
</div>

<div class="box-tocart"></div>
<div class="page-footer"></div>
```